# How to insert to parent and child table simultaneously in Flasksqlachemy?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using FlaskSqlachemy with Postgresql database.

I have a table called Order and a table called Attempt (attempt to deliver the order) in a one-to-many relationship. Attempt table has a FK for order.id .

I want to insert records both to Order and Attempt table in the same session. The problem is I don't know the order.id before inserting it. That's because order.id is the PK of Order table with auto-increment function.

I can insert first the order, then check the order.id, and finally insert the attempt. My problem is: if the second insert fails, I end up with an order that has no attempt associated with it.

What's the best practice in this cases?

Below is a simplified version of my db models:

```
class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    attempts = db.relationship('Attempt', backref='order', lazy='select',
                               order_by="Attempt.date")

class Attempt(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_id = db.Column(None, db.ForeignKey('order.id'))
```

And bellow my solution for now:

```
    # Create an order object
    new_order = Order()

    # Try to add it to db
    try:
        db.session.add(new_order)
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception:
        ....
        return redirect(url_for('scheduleorder'))
    else:
        order = Order.query.filter_by(token=token).first()

        # Create an attempt object
        new_attempt = Attempt(order_id=order.id)
        try:
            db.session.add(new_attempt)
            db.session.commit()
        except Exception:
            ...
            return redirect(url_for('scheduleorder'))
        else:
            ...
            return redirect(url_for('scheduleorder'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `commit()` which persists the changes to your database I would suggest to use `flush()`. Flush pushes the changes to the databases transactional buffer i.e your object is created and placed inside a buffer but not really written to you db as a record. This is so because down the line in that session if a exception occurs as in your case if a insert command fails we will use `rollback()` method to rollback to previous state.

---

This fits perfectly to your usecase as when you create a object and use flush method you can get access to the id which was autoincremented in the db, in your code to be used further down the line. On encountering exception do not forget to use db.session.rollback() to actually rollback the transaction.

```
# Create an order object
    new_order = Order()

    # Try to add it to db
    try:
        db.session.add(new_order)
        db.session.flush()
        order_id = new_order.id

    except Exception:
        ....
        db.session.rollback()
        return redirect(url_for('scheduleorder'))
    else:

        # Create an attempt object
        new_attempt = Attempt(order_id=order_id)
        try:
            db.session.add(new_attempt)
            db.session.flush()
        except Exception:
            ...
            db.session.rollback()
            return redirect(url_for('scheduleorder'))
        else:
            ...
            return redirect(url_for('scheduleorder'))

    # use the commit at the end of you usecase so that you actually create a record in your database.
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. Can I commit the changes on the second try block instead of the second flush? About the db.session.rollback(), I thought Sqlalchemy would automatically rollback in that case.. nice tip. Thank you

Comment: Yes you can use commit instead of second flush if you are sure that your usecase or transaction is over at that point and want to presist the data in your db. For the rollback while it is true that sqlalchemy rollsback if there is an exception and you didnt handel it, but since you've handeled it here , if somewhere you have used commit, then it would create a invalid record , so its better to be specific and mention rollback whenever you handel your exception. Makes for a cleaner code too, as well as improves the readability of the code.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help.